# Where can I find a repair diagram for Sony SELP1650 lens?

Tags: sony, repair, diy

I dropped my Sony a6000 and the lens took the impact (SELP1650) rendering it useless. Is there a site where I can get an exploded diagram? I intend to fix this myself. Also, if anyone knows where I can source the broken parts I would be very grateful.

Comment: googling for "16pz50 lens" only returns links to your question - maybe that's not the correct lens model

Comment: Obviously it's the Sony Sel16pz50 model.google is useless hence my question to a better informed forum. I hoped.

Comment: http://www.dpreview.com/forums/post/51664794

Comment: I searched for Sel16pz50 and, again, found nothing.  Not sure why I bothered to keep going but, having established that the model number is SELP1650 I found [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VACGVOSG7a4) and [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XxPLQbQBcA0) which may be of help. I'll see if I can find a definition of "obvious" for you - as I don't think it means what you think it means. And if "google is useless" I have nothing but sympathy for the people who request 3.5 billion searches on it each day.

Comment: Stop searching you've only found what I have seen already like I said Google is useless in supplying an answer to this. I was hoping someone who had experienced this issue might be able to help. With a link to a drawing.Cheers

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, claiming that google is useless is apparently an exaggeration. Assuming the lens is a model SELP1650, I found a service manual here: http://elektrotanya.com/sony_sal1650_ver.1.4.pdf/download.html . Even if it is not a perfect match, it may be able to help you. I have serviced perhaps 10 lenses over the years, and I have never had the benefit of a service manual. Although, the lenses I was servicing were old manual lenses, which are probably a lot easier than a newer electronic one. Good luck.

Comment: Maybe an exaggeration admit but I am proved correct again. The drawing you provided was for the alpha mount lens SAL1650. I will probably attempt to fix this without the manual. I needed the drawing to just identify which part was broken.Thanks.

Comment: Well then, perhaps Sony support is a better place for you to ask. It is probable that they only provide this information to authorized service centers, but it would not hurt to try.

Answer (score 0):

For all those looking for the same information I found the parts drawing here
http://www.searspartsdirect.com/model-part/selp1650/0996/0500140/50041709/00001.html

[image]

Comment: Wow! You can actually buy camera lens _parts_ from the Sears Catalogue? Will wonders never cease! (_only somewhat tongue-in-cheek_)